# How to add multiple "OR" queries in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, `Item` and `Category`, the model `Item` has category field as a foreign key

In my `views.py` I get a list of queries from a POST request `queries = ['category1', 'category2', 'category3', ...]`

I don't know the number of the queries I will get from the request, and I want to filter the `Item` model based on category field

I tried this

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Item, Category
from django import views

class myView(views.View):
    def post(self, request):
        queries = request.POST.get('queries', '')
        if queries:
            queriesList = []
            queries = queries.split(',')  # queries = ['category1', 'category2', ....]
            for query in queries:
                queriesList.append(Q(category__icontains=query))
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(*queriesList) # this will do AND but won't do OR
            # I tried: queryset = Item.objects.filter([q | Q() for q in queriesList]) but it didn't work
```

Also I tried `queryset = Item.objects.filter(category__in=queries)`
but it's case sensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Q.OR` as `_connector`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

from django import views

from .models import Category, Item


class myView(views.View):
    def post(self, request):
        queries = request.POST.get('queries', '')
        if queries:
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(
                *[Q(category__icontains=query) for query in queries.split(',')],
                _connector=Q.OR
            )
```

searching is however normally done through a GET request, such that the search query appears in the URL, and thus the URL can be copied, bookmarked, etc. with the search query included.

Comment: Is `_connector` in the Django documentation? If not, the leading underscore by convention means "do not touch unless you are maintaining the source code". (`_meta` is the exception, because it IS documented). I much prefer lampslave's answer, because it's clearer and does not rely on any "special" knowledge.

Comment: @nigel222: it is used on `deconstruct`, which means that it appears that way in a migration if you for example work with `limit_choices_to=Q(foo='a') | Q(bar='c')`, it will appear as `limit_choices_to=models.Q(('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), _connector='OR')` making it even more safe, snce migrations should be backward comaptible. `.filter(*args, **kwargs)` will first construct a `Q` object with `Q(*args, **kwargs)` so it exposes the same interface. Using binary operators is just a way to work with such `_connector`.

Comment: This is ok until you want to add more conditions to filter, `(name='myname', *[...], _connector=Q.OR)` will select items with specified name or any category instead of name and any category.

Comment: @lampslave: that is because the positional parameters should occur before the named ones, so: `(*[...], name='myname', _connector=Q.OR)`, or if you want to use an `AND` between the `[..]` and the `name='myname'`, you use: `(Q(*[...], _connector=Q.OR), name='myname')` this thus means that the category is one of the defined ones, *and* the name should (always) be `'myname'`.

Comment: It was a pseudocode, I mean that connector will be applied to whole .filter() what may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @lampslave: how would that be unexpected behavior, you have filters out of the list of `Q` objects, and the `name=` filter here, and you all group these with an or connector. This is almost self-explaining. If you want more complicated ones, you just construct `Q` objects. For two items, binary objects are indeed nice, for a list of filters that you want to combine, using the `_connector` is simply what happens behind the curtains. It is also how Django does this often for its contrib packages: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py#L88

Comment: This behavior will be unexpected for not experienced ones who will copy-paste you answer without any attempt to understand it and try to add more conditions later :)

Comment: I just suggest you to wrap code inside filter into Q, just like in the code of django :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
q = Q()

for category in ['category1', 'category2', 'category3', ...]:
    q |= Q(category__icontains=category)

items = Item.objects.filter(q)
```

If `Item.category` is a foreign key, maybe you want to use something like `category__name__icontains=category`.